# CocosSharp move sprite over an arc

Tags: xamarin, cocossharp

I'm working on a game in Xamarin. I have a plane that I want to fly from one side of an arc to the other while rotating the plane so the plane stays parallel to the arc.

Any suggestions?

[image]

**Update**

I was able to get this to work using a combination of CCBezierTo and CCRotateTo.

Comment: I understand the purpose of StackOverflow. Since CocosSharp has almost no documentation and very, very few samples that I could find, this is pretty much my only option. I'm looking for a suggestion/starting place. I'm not asking for a complete solution on how to do this.While continuing to dig through the API, should I find something, I'll update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my update I was able to accomplish this by using a combination of CCBezier and CCRotateTo.

```
        var duration = 5.0f;
        mysprite.RunActionAsync(new CCBezierTo(duration, new CCBezierConfig()
        {
            ControlPoint1 = new CCPoint(180, 200),
            ControlPoint2 = new CCPoint(650, 600),
            EndPosition = new CCPoint(1130, 200)
        }));

        mysprite.RunActionAsync(new CCRotateTo(duration, 90));
```

The ControlPoint2 is the top of the arc.